# Displaying a modal view on app start up leaves view hidden behind another

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to run a method when my app launches which involves presenting a modal view. The modal view appears as I can see it cover the status bar but it never comes over the front of the existing view.

I've tried this in the viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated method but that makes no difference to the problem.

If I call the method and present the modal view by tapping a button once the app loads it appears on top as it should.

Am I missing something or is there a way to force the modal view to come to the front when it appears?

The code I'm using to present the view is like this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
ModalView *modalView = [[ModalView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalView" bundle:nil];
modalView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
[modalView release];
}
```

It is however a call to an SDK called ZBar so I've also sent a question to them to find out if anything odd is going on in case it's not anything I'm doing.

Comment: I had the same problem two days ago. Can you show your code please ? Do you need a transition to show your view ?

Comment: My code for the view is pretty much this. -   (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    ModalView *modalView = [[ModalView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalView" bundle:nil];
    modalView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
    [modalView release];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your situation may be more complex, but i just wrote up a very simple app that does nothing but load a modal view at it's start.

in the main view controller, i add the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    ModalView *modalView = [[ModalView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalView" bundle:nil];
    modalView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    [self presentModalViewController:modalView animated:YES];
    [modalView release];
}
```

ModalView is just a stock UIViewController with an XIB file created with its associated file.  Then, of course, i import the ModalView.h header into my main view controller for the app.  i hope this helps.  if there's more to it, please feel free to post more and we can try to modify the code as necessary

Comment: I followed the code you suggested. The only missing part was the UIModalPresentationFullScreen bit. Unfortunately it still comes out the same.

Comment: that's definitely odd because this code should work.  i'm sorry i can't be of more help.  i would assume something is not fully loaded when the method is called.  if your question to ZBar comes back without any help, setting up a delay on the method may be the best solution.  this ensures that the app is fully loaded and can call your method safely.  in the meantime, i would suggest setting up NSLog statements both in your view controller and the modal view controller you set up to see what is loaded and when

Comment: Seems my issue may be more that my view is loading twice. The first time when I load the modal view is covered because the nib is loading a second time without the first releasing from what I can tell.

Comment: If that is the case, you may want to set up a check to see if the view exists before trying to allocate a new one.  In your primary view controller's header file, try setting up `ModalView *modalView;`.  Then when you call `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {`, you can ask the program if the view exists with `if (modalView != nil) { modalView = nil; [modalView release]; }` and continue the code as shown, but now you only need to say `modalView = [[ModalView alloc]...` instead of `ModalView *modalView = ...`

Comment: I've moved my code into the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: section and that's worked for me. It just seems that the app wasn't fully loading the view early enough for what I was trying to do. Upon reflection it seems that it likely wasn't best to try and implement some running code to do things in the app while the view was still in the loading stages. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear it.  Sometimes parts of our code don't load up as fast as we'd like, but it's great to hear you've got it all working now.  Much luck with the rest of your coding

Comment: Adding modalView helps me in my app. But where and how to dismiss it?

Comment: You can dismiss the modal view from the view that called the modal view using [viewThatCalledTheModalView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]. Sorry for the delayed response. I haven't logged on in way too long